# Count roles that have the same value in another role

Tags: mysql, database

How do I select number of titles that has the same role value for producer, writer, writer?

Took looks something like this,

```
title | year | person | role(actor, director, producer or writer)
```

The reasoning should be along the line,

```
SELECT COUNT(title) 
FROM movie_table 
WHERE role(writer,director, producer)= same person
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show the database structure.  There is no clear correlation between your tables like person_works_in and the data in the first code block.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(title) 
from movie_table
WHERE role in ('producer', 'writer')
and movie_person is not null
group by title
having count(distinct role) = 2
and count(distinct movie_person) = 1
```

Comment: Sorry for the mix up, person_works_in should be movie_table... so it's one table I'm querying. Table has (title, year, person, role) so I'm trying to get the title which has the same person as producer, writer, director. Link to the table http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/11234805/img/11234805.png

Comment: Ignore the table structure posted, use the link

Comment: That didn't solve it. Can you explain how you got having count(disctinct role) = 2 ... I'm I not suppose to be comparing roles say something like WHERE role in ('producer') = role in ('writer') ?

Comment: When I ran your query, it gave me the error 'ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'role) = 2' at line 1'

Comment: The `where` clause reduces the results to roles either `producer` or `writer`. And the `having` clause selects only the titles where both roles are in.

Comment: it ran but it still didn't answer my question. I'm not trying to get titles where both roles i.e producer and writer are in. which is what I think the result set was. Let's look at it this way. A  movie can have the same person as producer and writer. What I want to do is get how many movies exhibit that characteristic.

Comment: Ah, very close but it still returned title with null producer etc .. check out the link http://picturepush.com/public/11235236 "After Hours" was among the result set when I ran the query.. Also, how can I return just the number of movies that has this characteristic, i.e a single integer.

Comment: I updated again. If it does not work then please provide an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: It returned a long list of 2s under a column named count(title) .. I think I will be able to fine tune the query to get it to work now that I know about distinct and having... so would stop to bother you. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join (not to the same row) with optional join conditions:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.title)
FROM movie_table t1
JOIN movie_table t2 ON t1.id != t2.id 
    AND (t1.writer = t2.writer
      OR t1.director = t2.director
      OR t1.producer = t2.producer)
```